# Spring Webflow transition to the next state with Button eventid

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-webflow-2

I have a main flow, which is the link from index.jsp, the entry point of the test application that links into a subflow. The mainflow is main-flow.xml and is mapped to main.htm in the bean declaration with class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController".

In the main flow view there is the link 

                    Systeme suchen

that links to the subflow.

In the subflow I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
    start-state="Search">


    <view-state id="Search" view="/Search" >
        <transition on="proceed" to="temp" />
        <transition on="cancel" to="SubEnd" />
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="temp" view="/End" />


    <view-state id="SubEnde" view="/Start" />

</flow>
```

The view for Search does not contain any logic right now, just a link and a button. The JSPs for End.jsp does only contain some lore ipsum static content and Start is the same view that the main flow uses.

The Search.jsp link and buttons:

This works:

```
<a href="main.htm?_flowExecutionKey=${flowExecutionKey}&_eventId=proceed">
                    <span>Proceed Link</span></a>
```

This won't and just show a "description The requested resource is not available." site:

```
<a href="${flowExecutionKey}&_eventId=proceed">
                    <span>Proceed Link 2</span></a>     
<a href=_eventId=proceed">
                <span>Proceed Link 3</span></a>
```

And the button just doesn't do anything all:

```
<input type="submit" value="Proceeding" name="_eventId_proceed" id="eventId_proceedButton1">
```

What is going wrong here? I have seen numerous examples out in the internet for buttons specified like that. Am I missing some configuration for buttons or what?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using button, you need to do it via jquery or javascript. Something like on the event of button click perform the following:

```
document.getElementById('<yourFormName>').action = '${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=<yourEventID>';

document.getElementById('<yourFormName>').submit();
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

you should add hidden field for keeping SnapShot variable(means localhost:8080/yourappcontext/yourpage?execution=**e1s1**). In above url **e1s1** is SnapShot variable's value. So in your case :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
<input type="submit" value="Proceeding" name="_eventId_proceed"/>
```

But both tags should be stay in form tag.